# Where to download and install Oracle Directory Manager?

Tags: oracle, download-manager

Would someone please tell me specifically where can I download Oracle Directory Manager component? I know it's in one of the Oracle 10g discs but which one? Database, Client or Companion CD.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for *odm* or *oidadmin* you get a few pointers, such as [this forum post](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=1080457).  So it seems it's part of the client suite, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/oracle10g/htdocs/10201winsoft.html)